# running a jar file using -cp in cmd

Tags: java

```
myJar.jar
|-- classes
    |-- packageA
        |-- ClassA.class
    |-- packageB
        |-- ClassB.class
```

This is my JAR structure which I created using this command:

```
jar -cvf myJar.jar classes
```

And compiled my code using this command:

```
javac -d classes packageA/ClassA.java packageB/ClassB.java   .
```

When I try to run it using:

```
java -cp "myJar.jar;myJar.jar/classes" packageB.ClassB
```

it shows `ClassNotFoundException`.
Note: `ClassB` contains `main` method.

I tried creating another JAR which contains only `packageA` and `packageB` without `classes` folder and it works, but if I include `classes` folder in JAR also, it doesn't work.

```
myJar.jar
    |-- packageA
        |-- ClassA.class
    |-- packageB
        |-- ClassB.class
```

Comment: you do not want to add `classes` itself to the JAR (unless your package is `classes.packageA` or similar) - have a look at the `-C dir` option of `jar`: [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jar.html)

Comment: @user85421 is correct. So you want something like `jar cvfe myJar.jar packageB.ClassB -C classes .` Run from *above* directory 'classes'

Comment: I suggest that you read the documentation for the [jar command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jar.html) and also maybe the JAR file [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/jar/jar.html).

Comment: BTW (afaik) you cannot *address*  a folder inside a JAR like in `java -cp myJar.jar/classes` - at least I cannot find anything similar in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/java.html)

Comment: Thanks, everyone after reading the documentation it is clear that there is no way around the undefined folders included in the JAR as a container of packages.

Comment: Yes, but that that's not a problem - just make sure it doesn't get in there ;)